# Check if call to a method is made from another method using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am quite new to Moq and I am not sure is this even possible, but let say, if I have one method named `GeneratedHashedAndSaltedPassword()`and I am making a call to that method from method named `CheckUsersPassword()` is there any chance that i can write from Unit test Moq expression that says: Verify if `GeneratedHashedAndSaltedPassword` is call from `CheckUsersPassword` method?

I will know that `CheckUsersPassword` method preformed correctly if it makes a call to `GeneratedHashedAndSaltedPassword` method without any exception.

What I have for now is not much, since I am having difficult time with Moq and it's logic.

```
[Test]
public void CheckIfPasswordIsHashed_Test()
{
    var securityServiceMock = new Mock<User>();
    securityServiceMock.Setup(m => m.CheckUsersPassword(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
    securityServiceMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

I was trying to SetUp CheckUsersPassword, but I still don't know how or even if I can preform Verification I need. Does somebody has more experience with this kind of issue?

This is what CheckUserPassword does:

```
public bool CheckUsersPassword(string password)
{
    return SecurityService.GenerateHashedAndSaltedPassword(password, Salt) == Password;
}
```

It makes simple call to `GenerateHashedAndSaltedPassword()` and compares result with current user password.

Comment: Is SecurityService instance injected into the constructor of the class that contains the `CheckUsersPassword` method?

Comment: sure looks like a public static method to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important is to distinguish between code which is tested with unit test and external dependencies of this code. External dependencies are mocked with MOQ but tested code must be instantiated and called in the unit test directly.

In your question I assume you test the method `CheckUsersPassword` and that `SecurityService` is a dependency which should be mocked.

In the test you have to create instance of class (which contains the tested method) and pass mock of dependency to this tested class somehow.

```
[Test]
public void CheckIfPasswordIsHashed_Test()
{
    // Arrange
    // Mock dependency which is the service and setup
    // GenerateHashedAndSaltedPassword so it does what you need  
    var securityServiceMock = new Mock<User>();
    securityServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GenerateHashedAndSaltedPassword(
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        ItIsAny<Salt>())
    .Returns(Password);

    // TestedClass needs a place where the mocked instance can be injected,
    // e.g. in constructor, or public property
    var testedClass = new TestedClass(securityServiceMock.Object);

    // Act
    testedClass.CheckUsersPassword(password);

    // Assert
    securityServiceMock.Verify(m => m.GenerateHashedAndSaltedPassword(
        It.IsAny<string>(), 
        ItIsAny<Salt>()), 
    Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In meantime I've realized that external dependencies in unit that is tested must be mocked with Moq, but tested code must be real instance :) But it is great that we have such a good explanation here :) @dee